# Get same completion candidates for IMain as would appear in a REPL

Tags: scala, autocomplete, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to get the code completion for a Scala interpreter to work. Ideally it would work identically to the one provided by the REPL (`ILoop`). I am using a text document as source, so I do not want to instantiate an `ILoop` but just `IMain`.

In the following example, the completion only works for special cases:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.{JLineCompletion, IMain}
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings

object CompletionTest extends App {
  val settings  = new Settings
  settings.usejavacp.tryToSetFromPropertyValue("true")
  val intp      = new IMain(settings)
  intp.initializeSynchronous()
  assert(intp.isInitializeComplete)
  val comp      = new JLineCompletion(intp)
  val completer = comp.completer()
  val buffer    = "val x = Indexe"
  val choices   = completer.complete(buffer, buffer.length)
  println("----BEGIN COMPLETION----")
  choices.candidates.foreach(println)
  println("----END COMPLETION----")
  intp.close()
}
```

The expected output would be `IndexedSeq`, but it is empty. If I set the buffer to just `Indexe`, it works. If I set the buffer to   `Indexe` (leading whitespace), the completion candidates are empty again.

So there must be an additional step involved in processing the buffer or invoking the completion. What exactly happens when `<tab>` is pressed in the REPL? It seems almost impossible to figure out which methods are called...

Comment: I have tried to use `ILoop` instead, the same problem occurs. So it must be the way I invoke the completer that is wrong or insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `JLineReader`, you can see the wiring.  `JLineConsoleReader` sets up an `ArgumentCompleter` with the `ScalaCompleter` as the underlying completer.

So the completer wants just the argument, not the line.

```
apm@mara:~$ scalam
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-M7 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._, definitions._ also imported    **
** Try  :help, :vals, power.<tab>           **

scala> val b = "Indexe"
b: String = Indexe

scala> completion.completer complete (b, b.length)
res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Completion.Candidates = Candidates(0,List(IndexedSeq))
```

In other keystrokes,

```
// paste your code

scala> val buffer    = "Indexe"
buffer: String = Indexe

scala> completer.complete(buffer, buffer.length)
res6: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Completion.Candidates = Candidates(0,List(IndexedSeq))

scala> import tools.nsc.interpreter.Completion.Candidates
import tools.nsc.interpreter.Completion.Candidates

scala> val Candidates(_, choices) = completer.complete(buffer, buffer.length)
choices: List[String] = List(IndexedSeq)

scala> choices foreach println
IndexedSeq
```

To hand it the full line:

```
scala> val argCompletor: ArgumentCompleter =new ArgumentCompleter(new JLineDelimiter, scalaToJline(comp.completer))
argCompletor: jline.console.completer.ArgumentCompleter = jline.console.completer.ArgumentCompleter@751222c7

scala> val maybes = new java.util.ArrayList[CharSequence]
maybes: java.util.ArrayList[CharSequence] = []

scala> val buffer    = "val x = Indexe"
buffer: String = val x = Indexe

scala> argCompletor.setStrict(false)

scala> argCompletor.complete(buffer, buffer.length, maybes)
res32: Int = 8

scala> maybes
res33: java.util.ArrayList[CharSequence] = [IndexedSeq]
```

The delimiter does the line parse.

Edit - some value-added analysis:

"Strict" mode for the completor exists because you can supply a completor for each token on the line, and require each previous argument to be completable.  For n completors, all args after nth arg are handled by the last completor.

Comment: Any clues who to strip this down for direct use with `IMain`?

Comment: It works for `val b = "Indexe"`, but not for `val b = "val b = Indexe"`. That is to say, `JLine` in `ConsoleReader` does some massage to find the right spot it seems. I guess I have to drill open `ConsoleReader` if I want to have programmatic access

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of delimiter and strict! I'm curious—since the delimiter doesn't take the interpreter as argument: Do you know, is this a pure local syntax parse without invoking anything inside the interpreter/`Global`?

Comment: @0__ just syntax splitting on delimiters, but there's a bug in quoting so eventually the complexity may go up. You're right the code stack is hard to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer. I managed to drill a hole in that monster by overriding `scalaToJline` in `JLineReader`. That method is invoked with a pre-massaged string, following this trace:

```
at CompletionTest$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anon$3.complete(CompletionTest.scala:37)
at scala.tools.jline.console.completer.ArgumentCompleter.complete(ArgumentCompleter.java:150)
at scala.tools.jline.console.ConsoleReader.complete(ConsoleReader.java:1543)
at scala.tools.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:1312)
at scala.tools.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:1170)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JLineReader.readOneLine(JLineReader.scala:74)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader$$anonfun$readLine$2.apply(InteractiveReader.scala:42)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader$$anonfun$readLine$2.apply(InteractiveReader.scala:42)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader$.restartSysCalls(InteractiveReader.scala:49)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader$class.readLine(InteractiveReader.scala:42)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JLineReader.readLine(JLineReader.scala:19)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.readOneLine$1(ILoop.scala:568)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:584)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:587)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this my "unwiring" which seems to be working as expected:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._
import scala.tools.jline.console.completer.{Completer, ArgumentCompleter}
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Completion.{Candidates, ScalaCompleter}
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import collection.JavaConverters._
```

```
object Completion2 extends App {
  val settings  = new Settings
  settings.usejavacp.tryToSetFromPropertyValue("true")
  val intp      = new IMain(settings)
  intp.initializeSynchronous()

  val completion = new JLineCompletion(intp)

  def scalaToJline(tc: ScalaCompleter): Completer = new Completer {
    def complete(_buf: String, cursor: Int, candidates: JList[CharSequence]): Int = {
      val buf   = if (_buf == null) "" else _buf
      val Candidates(newCursor, newCandidates) = tc.complete(buf, cursor)
      newCandidates foreach (candidates add _)
      newCursor
    }
  }

  val argCompletor: ArgumentCompleter =
    new ArgumentCompleter(new JLineDelimiter, scalaToJline(completion.completer()))
  argCompletor.setStrict(false)

  val jlist: java.util.List[CharSequence] = new java.util.ArrayList

  val buffer = "val x = Indexe"

  argCompletor.complete(buffer, buffer.length, jlist)

  val list = jlist.asScala

  println("----BEGIN COMPLETION----")
  list.foreach(println)
  println("----END COMPLETION----")
  intp.close()
}
```

---

**Edit:** This has problems with wildcard imports for some reason. Like if I execute

```
import mypackage.MySymbol
```

Then `MySymbol` is found by the completer. But if I execute instead

```
import mypackage._
```

Then none of the contents of `mypackage` are found. Any ideas?